# Pandas: datetime conversion from dtype object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I am working on a timeseries dataset which looks like this:

```
         DateTime         SomeVariable 
0   01/01 01:00:00          0.24244
1   01/01 02:00:00          0.84141
2   01/01 03:00:00          0.14144
3   01/01 04:00:00          0.74443
4   01/01 05:00:00          0.99999
```

The date is without year. Initially, the dtype of the DateTime is object and I am trying to change it to pandas datetime format. Since the date in my data is without year, on using:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime)
```

I am getting the error `OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 01:00:00`

I understand why I am getting the error (as it's not according to the pandas acceptable format), but what I want to know is how I can change the dtype from object to pandas datetime format without having year in my date. I would appreciate the hints.

EDIT 1:

Since, I got to know that I can't do it without having year in the data. So this is how I am trying to change the dtype:

```
df = pd.read_csv(some file location)
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime('2018/'+df['DateTime'], format='%y%d/%m %H:%M:%S')
df.head()
```

On doing that, I am getting:

```
ValueError: time data '2018/ 01/01 01:00:00' doesn't match format specified.
```

EDIT 2:

Changing the format to `'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'`.
My data is hourly data, so it goes till 24h. I have only provided the demo data till 5h. 
I was getting the space on adding the year to the DateTime. In order to remove that, this is what I did:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime('2018/'+df['DateTime'][1:], format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I am getting the following error for that:

```
ValueError: time data '2018/ 01/01  02:00:00' doesn't match format specified
```

On changing the format to `'%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'` with the same code,  this is the error I get:

```
ValueError: time data '2018/ 01/01  02:00:00' does not match format '%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S' (match)
```

The problem is because of the gap after the year but I am not able to get rid of it.

EDIT 3:

I am able to get rid of the space after adding the year, however I am still not able to change the dtype.

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime('2018/'+df['DateTime'].str.strip(), format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

ValueError: time data '2018/01/01  01:00:00' doesn't match format specified
```

I noticed that there are 2 spaces between the date and the time in the error, however adding 2 spaces in the format doesn't help.

**EDIT 4 (Solution)**:

Removed all the multiple whitespaces. Still the format was not matching. The problem was because of the time format. The hours were from 1-24 in my data and pandas support 0-23. Simply changed the time 24:00:00 to 00:00:00 and it works perfectly now.

Comment: Or change your format to `'%y %d/%m %H:%M:%S'`.

Comment: I had already tried the 2nd suggestion of changing the format to '%y %d/%m %H:%M:%S'. It results in ValueError: time data '2018/ 01/01  01:00:00' does not match format '%y %d/%m %H:%M:%S' (match)

Comment: You are also not using capitalization correctly. Please check my answer again. For example, `%Y` means something different to `%y`.

Comment: I tried with 'Y' as well, still the same error.

Comment: The error can't *possibly* be the same since your previous error had `'%y %d/%m %H:%M:%S'` in it... you need to provide a [mcve] for us to help. This includes some accurate data (with spaces and all) as well as code / error messages.

Comment: Let me edit the code and the error in the question

Comment: I have edited the code in the question.

Comment: `df['DateTime'][1:]` won't select the substring as you intend to do. It will select all but the first entry from the column `'DateTime'` without changing them. Then `'%y %d/%m %H:%M:%S'` won't macht if the slash `'/'` is still in your date string... That's why both solutions didn't work. Please read your error messages carefully, they tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Just do `df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime('2018/'+df['DateTime'].str.strip(), format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')`.

Comment: @swenzel Thanks, your suggestion helps me to get rid of the space after the year, but i am still not able to change the dtype. I have explained it in the question.

Comment: That's some nasty fromat you got there! :D `.str.replace(r'\s+', ' ')` will replace multiple whitespaces with a single space.

Comment: I know, unnecessary complication :(. Got rid of all the multiple whitespaces. Still, the format doesn't match. Is it because the hours in my data are from 1-24?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. A `datetime` object *must* have a year.

What you *can* do is ensure all years are aligned for your data.

For example, to convert to `datetime` while setting year to 2018:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': ['01/01 01:00:00', '01/01 02:00:00', '01/01 03:00:00',
                                '01/01 04:00:00', '01/01 05:00:00']})

df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime('2018/'+df['DateTime'], format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

print(df)

             DateTime
0 2018-01-01 01:00:00
1 2018-01-01 02:00:00
2 2018-01-01 03:00:00
3 2018-01-01 04:00:00
4 2018-01-01 05:00:00
```

Comment: For me the year is getting added but I am getting ValueError: time data '2018/ 01/01  01:00:00' doesn't match format specified.

Comment: No, just added the year to the dataframe like you. I will update the code in my question the way I have done it.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Remove spaces. Have in mind this will remove all spaces.
df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].str.replace(" ", "")

# I'm assuming year does not matter and that 01/01 is in the format day/month.
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='%d/%m%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: On doing this, I get the following error:
ValueError: time data ' 01/01  01:00:00' does not match format '%d/%m %H:%M:%S' (match)

Comment: @NOOB I edited the answer to accomodate your undesired space in the middle of the string problem.